# mustache template to work with an object having series of named objects

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine, mustache

Need help with the following template to sort out the given json data. each object inside is another named object, is there a way to simply iterate through the list.

so far unable to find an example that deals with this case. Kindly help.

```
{
"6gb1": {
    "id": "b7e3b34b-7f15-4221-9601-69899a29c738",
    "productId": "6gb1",
    "title": "Social Studies",
    "folioNumber": "1",
    "publicationDate": "2014-01-10T05:00:00.000Z",
    "targetDimensions": ["1024x768"],
    "folioDescription": "Social Studies",
    "manifestXRef": "Social Studies",
    "previewImageURL": "",
    "isFree": true
},
"5gb2": {
    "id": "65017770-bd01-47a2-867b-46948ea58d4c",
    "productId": "5gb2",
    "title": "Algebra",
    "folioNumber": "1",
    "publicationDate": "2014-01-10T05:00:00.000Z",
    "targetDimensions": ["1024x768"],
    "folioDescription": "Algebra",
    "manifestXRef": "Algebra",
    "previewImageURL": "",
    "isFree": true
},
"5gb1": {
    "id": "b1148439-1b18-4b63-8d92-b3a4051286af",
    "productId": "5gb1",
    "title": "English",
    "folioNumber": "1",
    "publicationDate": "2014-01-10T05:00:00.000Z",
    "targetDimensions": ["1024x768"],
    "folioDescription": "English",
    "manifestXRef": "English",
    "previewImageURL": "",
    "isFree": true
},
"6gb2": {
    "id": "0199ac64-3f20-45f9-ba70-883f95ab0e58",
    "productId": "6gb2",
    "title": "Environmental Science",
    "folioNumber": "1",
    "publicationDate": "2014-01-10T05:00:00.000Z",
    "targetDimensions": ["1024x768"],
    "folioDescription": "Environmental Science",
    "manifestXRef": "Environmental Science",
    "previewImageURL": "",
    "isFree": true
}
}
```

and the template is

```
<script id="folioTemplate" type="text/template">
{{#folios}}
<li class='folio clearfix'>
     {{folioDescription}}
    <div id='title'>{{{title}}}</div>
</li>
{{/folios}}
</script>
```

and the script is

```
document.getElementById("folios").innerHTML = Mustache.render(document.getElementById('folioTemplate').innerHTML, {'folios': folios});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepare your values before passing them to Mustache:

```
var values = [];
for (var key in folios) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(folios, key)) {
    values.push(folios[key]);
  }
}

var tpl = document.getElementById('folioTemplate').innerHTML;
document.getElementById("folios").innerHTML = Mustache.render(tpl, {'folios': values});
```